# Given matrix $A$, find matrix $X$ such that $e^X = A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-exponential

Given the following matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 2 & 1\\ 2 & -3 & -2\\ -5 & 6 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$

how can we show that there exists a complex matrix $X$ such that $e^X = A$.

I have struggled to find the information about workaround the problem. However, the determinant of matrix $A$ is non-zero and its eigenvalues are $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: In order that there exist e^x= A, ln(A) must exist because we must have x= ln(A).  And that is defined, for matrices, using the McLaurin series for ln(A), $1+ A+ A^2/2+ A^3/3+ ...$.  You say that "Eigenvalues are -1 and 1".  Since this is a 3 by 3 matrix is there another eigenvalue?  What are the corresponding eigenvectors?  If you know that you may be able to "diagonalize" A which would make the computation much easier.

Comment: And what is $x$ supposed to be?

Comment: X is a complex matrix

Comment: Hello, I gave an answer that I now deleted. My argument applied for normal matrices, but then I realized $A$ is not normal and this is why I deleted it

Comment: @user247327 Also the logarithm should have alternating signs and every instance of $A$ should be replaced by $A - I$, I believe.

Comment: @user247327 is it possible that ln(x) can have McLaurin series? Can you clarify this one? Please!

Comment: I miswrote.  I should have said "Taylor's series" around x= 1.  Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Jordan form of $A$ is given by $$J = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
with $A = PJP^{-1}$ where $P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$.

First we can try to find $\log J$ blockwise. Searching for the logarithm of $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ again as some Jordan block, if we set $f(x) = e^{-x}$ then
$$\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix} i\pi & -1 \\ 0 & i\pi\end{bmatrix}\right) = f\left(\begin{bmatrix} -i\pi & 1 \\ 0 & -i\pi\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix} f(-i\pi) & f'(-i\pi) \\ 0 & f(-i\pi)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$
so we can set (clearly it's not unique)
$$\log J = \begin{bmatrix} i\pi & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & i\pi & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
and finally we get
$$\log A = P(\log J) P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & -1\end{bmatrix}+i\pi \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & 1 \\ 2 & -2 & -1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Sir, why did you take only the block matrix for the map f(x)=exp(-x) , while you can take the full J. Then there should be different answer,(what you have said?).

Comment: @Subhajit Logarithm of the $1\times 1$ block $[1]$ is simply $[0]$ so taking the logarithm blockwise we get $$\log J = \begin{bmatrix} \log \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix} & \\ & \log [1]\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} i\pi & -1 \\ 0 & i\pi\end{bmatrix} & \\ & [0]\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} i\pi & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & i\pi & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks, it was a typo.